# Differentiating between cases where user enters '0' or leaves TextBox empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, type-conversion

Well the question title may not be self explanatory, so let me go ahead and elaborate.

Consider, a *TextBox* that accepts *only numeric value or is left empty*. The value(text) entered is stored in an integer(*int32*) variable. The problem arises when the user enters the digit 0 or leaves the *TextBox* empty, as the conversion from string to int, converts an empty string to "0" as well.

**So my question stands**: *How do I differentiate the 2 scenarios?*

**EDIT** I figured a lot of questions may be answered by the **code** and exact problem(*as I see it*)

```
    if (txtOtherId.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        otherId = Convert.ToInt32(null);
    }
    else
    {
        otherId = Convert.ToInt32(txtOtherId.Text);
    }
```

Comment: if the TextBox is left empty it is not Zero.what type of converts are you applying over the textbox.

Comment: What type (`class`) is your text box. It doesn't seem like the standard conversions from `string` to `int` allow empty strings as input. How do you convert?

Comment: the text box is an *asp:TextBox* under *System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox*. I am using *Convert.ToInt32()* to convert the input string to integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried? Can we see your code?

Now, *I* tried the following:

```
int i;
i = Convert.ToInt32("");  // throws, doesn't give zero
i = int.Parse("");         // throws, doesn't give zero
bool couldParse = int.TryParse("", out i);   // makes i=0 but signals that the parse failed
```

So I can't reproduce. However, if I use `null` instead of `""`, the `Convert.ToInt32` does convert into zero (`0`). However, `Parse` and `TryParse` still fail with `null`.

UPDATE:

Now that I see your code. Consider changing the type of `otherId` from `int` to **`int?`** where the question mark makes it a *nullable* type. Then:

```
if (txtOtherId.Text == "")
{
    otherId = null;  // that's null of type int?
}
else
{
    otherId = Convert.ToInt32(txtOtherId.Text);   // will throw if Text is (empty again or) invalid
}
```

If you want to be sure no exceptions can happen, do this:

```
int tmp; // temporary variable
if (int.TryParse(txtOtherId.Text, out tmp))
    otherId = tmp;
else
    otherId = null;   // that's null of type int?; happens for all invalid input
```

Comment: Sorry for not providing the code as well. Please see my edit.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher OK, now I see that you're introducing the `null` yourself! Just don't do that. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I would very much appreciate if you could tell me how i may pass **otherId**(*null or otherwise*) as a parameter to my stored proc. I am facing a ***Nullable object must have a value*** exception when I try to pass `otherId.Value` as the parameter.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher I would need to see what code you use to create the stored procedure. In general I can say that writing `otherId.Value` will throw if it's `null`. How could it return an `int` when there is none? However it's OK to say e.g. `otherId.ToString()` in any case. It will give you `""` if `otherId` is null. It's also always OK to say `otherId.HasValue`, and it will tell you if there is a value or not. Maybe you need a ternary expression like `otherId.HasValue ? otherId.ToString() : "NULL"` for your code?

Comment: I used `if(otherId.HasValue)` to assist my logic. Thanks a lot for the clarifications and help.

Answer (score 2):

How about an extension method?

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static bool TryGetInt(this TextBox tb, out int value)
  {
    int i;
    bool parsed = int.TryParse(tb.Text, out i);
    value = i;

    return parsed;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
int i;

if (textBox1.TryGetInt(out i))
{
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
}
else
{
    // no integer entered
}
```

Comment: In your extension method, you really don't need that first part (the `if`), because `int.TryParse` already handles `null`, empty amd white-space strings the same way (`parsed` becomes false). So it's redundant. Your extension method is not really necessary because of this. (The premise in the original question was wrong.)

Comment: Fair point. Should have checked first (I thought the assumption sounded dodgy). Updated. Possibly not worth bothering with an extension method then.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [nullable int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and then have blank string be null.

```
int? myValue = String.IsNullOrEmpty(myTextbox.Text) 
        ? (int?)null 
        : int.Parse(myTextbox.Text);
```

For clarity, the above is equivalent to

```
int? myValue = null;
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(myTextbox.Text))
{
    myValue = int.Parse(myTextbox.Text);
}
```

Comment: Could you break it down to make it look cleaner.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher - huh? Its 1 line of code broken over 3 lines to make it easy to read. What's hard to understand? The fact it uses a ternary operator? Ok, i'll make it an `if....else`

Comment: my bad, i failed to make myself clear(*again!*). M fine with ur use of the ternary operator, just not so sure about the casting `(int?)int.Parse(myTextbox.Text);`

Comment: In the ternary version, you need to because otherwise you get the error `type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'int'`, but for the `if` version its not necessary at all.

Comment: Also, I had it on the wrong part of the ternary operator, it has to go against the `null` to cast the null to a nullable int.

Comment: Of course, in either case, the `Int32` value is being **wrapped** into an `Nullable<Int32>` struct, so there's still a conversion going on, but in the simple assignment the type can be inferred from the type of `myValue`, and the conversion can then be implicit.

Comment: @Jamiec No, it was fine to have the `(int?)` cast on the integer (rather than the null literal). Actually, I liked that more.

Comment: In this case, I actually prefer the syntax `default(Nullable<int>)` or `default(int?)` instead of `(int?)null` or `(Nullable<int>)null` - to me it seems to better indicate intent to someone reading the code later.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is indeed a textbox...

```
string result = myTextBox.Text;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    // This is an empty textbox
else
    // It has a number in it.
    int i = int.Parse(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There're 2 simple approaches how to do it:

```
string inputText="";

int? i=null;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputText))
i = int.Parse(inputText);

int i2;
bool ok = int.TryParse(inputText, out i2);
```